# How i insert a string from DataBase into a ListBox

Tags: c#

```
 string SQL = "SELECT * FROM Email ";
 string myConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
              "Data Source=" + textBox1.Text;
 OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnString);
 OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQL, myConnection);
 myConnection.Open();
 OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
 if (myReader.Read())
 {
    View.Items.Add(myReader.Read());
 }
 myConnection.Close();
```

The output is *False* .The output should be israel.nahum(from the DB)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which column you want to retrieve the text from:

```
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM Email ";
    string myConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + textBox1.Text;
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnString);
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQL, myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    //Changed if(myReader.Read()) to while(myReader.Read())
    while(myReader.Read())
    {
        View.Items.Add(myReader["NameOfColumnGoesHere"]);
    }



    myConnection.Close();
```

Take a look at [the documentation for the OleDbDataReader Class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @Israel, See above edit. Calling `myReader.Read()` advances to the first record. You want to read until all the records have been read, so you need to use `while(myReader.Read())`.

Answer (score 1):

Read get you access to the iterator (put the next item of the results in it) use

```
if (myReader.Read())
{
    View.Items.Add(myReader["COLUMN_NAME"]);
}
```

And so then, if the reader returns something then it'll put in on your item.

Comment: View.Items.Add(myReader["EMAIL"]);

Comment: I suggest to study first about what you're are trying to do. If you use if(myReader.Read()) then that code will evaluate just ONE time, for the first record. If you want it to perform for EACH record, then use WHILE

Answer (score 0):

Please look in MSDN documentation how to use the DataReader object. the Read is reading a row and returning true if there is any row available, you should use other methods to get the values from the current row.

also, notice that you do not need to do a `SELECT * FROM...` if you only need one column, just do `SELECT Email FROM ...` for example...